# Total amount of XTZ in existence

Tags: protocol, tzscan, api

Is there an RPC to get the total amount of tezos in existence at some particular block (or cycle begin/end)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current protocol does not keep track of a tally of all tez on the network. It would be a [good idea](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/316) to do so, as it permits computing proportional reward, it can serve as a canari against money printing bugs, and it can be used to refine the governance model.

Since the protocol doesn't keep track of it, there's no node RPC that will give you that information. However, some indexers, like tzscan, do keep track of that info, and they do expose RPCs

Comment: Curious as to why the current protocol doesn't keep track. Was this a design decision?

Comment: Because there's not a strong need to keep track. It enables certain things, so it's nice to have, but not necessary.

Answer (score 12):

TzScan has a service for that, but only for the current value:

```
https://api1.tzscan.io/v1/supply
```

returns

```
{
  "dls":"76431859801260",
  "foundation":"76431859801260",
  "early_bakers":"3156502294100",
  "contributors":"608297709519372",
  "unfrozen_rewards":"19546676770764",
  "missing_revelation":0,
  "revelation_rewards":968500000,
  "burned_tez_revelation":0,
  "burned_tez_origination":"3546923000",
  "burned_tez_double_baking":"153472908345",
  "total_supply_ico":"764317931415992",
  "circulating_supply":"783708546041411"
}
```

What you are looking for is probably `circulating_supply`.